# What is the significance of 7-month births?

Tags: history, time, pregnancy-birth

I have noticed that there are a number of significant figures in Jewish history who were born at 7 months. To name a few:

- Yitzchok Avinu ([Rosh Hashana 11a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=11&format=pdf))
- Reuvein, Shimon, and Levi (Rabbeinu Bachaye, Bereishis 35:30)
- The rest of the Shevatim (according to my assertion [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/65558/4794))
- Moshe Rabbeinu (Rashi, Shemos 2:3)
- Shmuel Hanovi ([Niddah 38b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=37&daf=38b&format=pdf))

What is the significance, symbolic or otherwise, to this phenomenon?

Comment: relevant: _"the Gemara (Shabbat 135a) states that a baby born in its eighth month from conception cannot survive and, therefore, Shabbat should not be violated to try to save it. However, a baby born in its seventh or ninth month is viable and Shabbat must be violated for its sake. "_ - http://www.aishdas.org/toratemet/science.html

Comment: children born at this time often have health issues. Perhaps the significance can be found in that specific people born in this time frame is they were born completely healthy and able to breathe on their own?

Comment: @sabbahillel What was the point of that edit? I don't see what improvement it made, and it changed the connotation from asking _if_ there is significance to assuming there is and asking what it is.

Comment: @yEz The last sentence in the question was "What is the significance" I changed the title to match it. If it is incorrect, make the last sentence and the title match.

Comment: @sabbahillel You changed the title after you approved an edit which changed the body of the question...

Comment: Don't forget Chur's and Bat-Sheva's ancestors (Sanhedrin 69b)

Comment: @Matt And Bat-Sheva herself, according to one step of the gemara IIRC. I only wanted "to name a few"

Comment: And chur himself, and Shelomo...

Comment: @yEz IMO you should feel free to rollback the edit if you feel it conflicts wit your intent.

Comment: Side point - There seems to be a distinction between 7 calendar months (approximately 30 weeks), 7 4-week "months" (28 weeks), and "7" months (partial month + 5 months + partial month - see Rashi Shemos 2:2-3). Also of relevance is that an "8-month" baby is either a premature 9-month, or an overly mature 7-month. Even modern OB/GYNs will induce an overly due mother to ensure that the baby doesn't aspirate and choke on it's own maconium. Something that was likely fatal during the Talmudical era.

Comment: @Menachem: The Gemara says no such thing. It says a preterm nine-month pregnancy that was born in the eighth month wouldn't live, but a post-term seven-month pregnancy would.

Comment: @DonielF: It's been a while, but I don't think that's the case. The whole point of the Gemara there is that if a baby is born in the 8th month it is a pre-term 9th month baby, not a post-term 7th month baby. That is why the baby is Muktzah

Comment: @Menachem: I apologize. I was mixing up the Gemara and the Midrash quoted in [RenatoGrun's answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/70852/9682). The full Midrash there differentiates between a post-term seven-month baby and a preterm nine-month baby, and according to one opinion, all eight-month babies can survive.

Answer (score 2):

a)  Seven month children would indicate resistence and longevity. The [Midrash Rabbah 14:2](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/tanach/raba1/14.htm) states:

> בעון קמיה דרבי אבהו:  מנין שהנוצר לשבעה חי?  אמר להון: מדידכון, אנא
>   ממטי לכון, זיט"א אפט"א, איט"א אוכט"א:
>
> They [some Greeks] asked R. Abahu: From where do you know that a fetus
>   formed at 7 months can live? He replied: From
>   your own [language] I will prove it to you: **zeta epta, eta octo** [this is a wordplay on "[*zeta — seven, eta — eight*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet#Origins)" also meaning something like "*fetuses of **seven** months are more likely to **survive** **than** those of **eight***" ("*Live, seven! Dying eight*")].

Therefore the seven month baby is not premature but a product of an alternative, faster maturation tract.

b)  Indicates a sign of greatness and prophecy. That would explain why [Midrash HaGadol on Shemos 2:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33185&st=&pgnum=18&hilite=) states:

> שכל הנביאים לא נולדו אלא לשבעה חדשים
>
> “all prophets were born at seven months"

Comment: Thanks for the info, but this somewhat begs the question. What is the symbolism or significance of 7 months? I suppose mefarshim on that Midrash HaGadol would be a good place to start.

Comment: I don't know about a, but b makes sense given that 7 indicates spirituality.

Answer (score 1):

I once heard a reason given that tzadikim, even at a young age, are eager to get out into the world and start doing mitzvos...