# Why Leah is so stressed?

Tags: pregnancy-birth, vayeitzei, imahot-matriarch-mothers

On Gen 30:9

> וַתֵּ֣רֶא לֵאָ֔ה כִּ֥י עָמְדָ֖ה מִלֶּ֑דֶת וַתִּקַּח֙ אֶת־זִלְפָּ֣ה
>   שִׁפְחָתָ֔הּ וַתִּתֵּ֥ן אֹתָ֛הּ לְיַעֲקֹ֖ב לְאִשָּֽׁה׃

When Leah saw that she had stopped bearing, she took her maid Zilpah and gave her to Jacob as concubine (Sefria translation. I translate wife.).

Sharing your husband with another wife is an act of stress, as we know from Abraham-Sara-Hagar, and from the Rachel, giving Biha to Yakkov only after she is stressed.

His twelve children were born during 7 years, and from simple look at the verses, none of his wives were pregnant simultaneously, [so one of his wives was pregnant all the time](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65545/how-did-jacob-manage-to-have-12-children-in-7-years?rq=1).

Why Leah is so stressed that she gives her maid to Yaakov as a wife? She has 4 children in a row, other then her only Bilha has kids - only two, and she is not giving birth for only 1.5-2~ years?

What is the rush?

Comment: Where does it say she was "stressed?" She found herself unable to bear Jacob children, and so provided Jacob one who could bear him children.

Comment: @SolaGratia Gen 30:1-3

Comment: Where is Leah mentioned in Genesis 30:1-3?

Comment: You may want to make it plainer that you are asking about Rachel. As for women in those ancient times, it was viewed as a "reproach" to not have children, and even a curse (1 Sam. 1:6). 1 Sam. 1:11: "And making a vow she said, O Lord of hosts, if you will look upon the humiliation of your maidservant, and remember me, and ...  give your maidservant ...offspring." Lk. 11:25 "This thing the Lord has done for me, in the days when he looked upon me to take away my disgrace among men." 1:48 "For he hath looked upon the humiliation of his handmaid."

Comment: @Alex You are right, that is a dup. Unfortunately, I can't accept the given answer, it's so far away from simple understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The Torah doesn't say anything about Leah being "stressed"  so that isn't a question anyone can answer.

However, to answer the question of why  Leah gave Zilpha to Yaakov the Ramban says two reasons

(1)She knew as a  Nevahua that  Yaakov would have twelve Shevatim so she wanted to have a part in as many as possible

(2)Yaakov wanted to have many children. She was concerned that since his other wives weren't having children he may have married a total stranger to have more children with her. Therefore she wanted him to marry Zilpha as opposed to   a total stranger.

Comment: Sharing your husband with another wife is an act of stress Gen 30:1-3